# How to make MySQL database backup?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

Μy code works properly in local host:

```
 Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump --host="  + host + " --port=" + port + 
            " --user=" + user + " --password=" + password +
            " --compact --databases --add-drop-table --complete-insert --extended-insert " +
            "--skip-comments --skip-triggers "+ db);
```

On local system I am using direct path `C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\`, but in the server I didn't get any direct path, I have only base directory.

After hosting MySQL databases, I got an exception:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program > "\usr\local\mysql-5.5.43\mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The > system cannot find the file specified

How can I get hosted MySQL databases backup to a local system, I would like to run the code in my locally?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the formatting - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: First guess: your hosting system is *nix machine, so you must use slashes (`/`) in the path. I.e. `...exec("/usr/local/mysql-5.5.43/mysqldump ...")`. Btw. most probably is the path to `mysqldump` executable `/usr/local/mysql-5.5.43/bin/mysqldump` (i.e. the executable is in `bin` sub-folder).

Comment: i check that also , no luck

Comment: Have you tried to execute the command on the propmpt? I think It could be a parameter problem.